# How can I find the name of the VM image used to create an Azure VM using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

If I use Get-AzureVM (PowerShell cmdlet) to fetch a running VM then the fields I get back are

```
DeploymentName
Name
Label
VM
InstanceStatus
IpAddress
InstanceStateDetails
PowerState
InstanceErrorCode
InstanceFaultDomain
InstanceName
InstanceUpgradeDomain
InstanceSize
HostName
AvailabilitySetName
DNSName
Status
GuestAgentStatus
ResourceExtensionStatusList
PublicIPAddress
PublicIPName
PublicIPDomainNameLabel
PublicIPFqdns
NetworkInterfaces
VirtualNetworkName
ServiceName
OperationDescription
OperationId
OperationStatus
```

However I cannot see the name of the image used to create the VM.  I can see this information using the Azure portal (under Settings > Properties > SOURCE IMAGE NAME).  How can I get the source image name using PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the source image ID from the operating system disk's properties.

Try this:

```
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName serviceName -Name vmName 
$vm.VM.OSVirtualHardDisk
```

Then you should get this for example:

```
HostCaching     : ReadWrite
DiskLabel       : 
DiskName        : multinicdemo-host1-0-201504131546160112
MediaLink       : https://multinicdemo.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/multinicdemo-host1-2015-4-13-17-46-7-664-0.vhd
SourceImageName : a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201503.01-en.us-127GB.vhd
OS              : Windows
IOType          : Standard
ResizedSizeInGB : 
ExtensionData   :
```

Or in one line:

```
(Get-AzureVM -ServiceName serviceName -Name vmName).VM.OSVirtualHardDisk.SourceImageName
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to check the source image without using cmd/Powershell, then  follow these steps:
How to find the running VM image version.

```
> Go to azure portal
> Select the running/stopped VM whose image you want to identify
> Go to export template option
> On the right side of the screen, you will see the template window will open in JSON format.
> Ctrl+F (search) > imageReference > you will get your image version in the template.
```

Answer (score 3):

In the new '**Az**' Powershell module you have to check for source image as below:

```
> $vm = (Get-AzVM -Name <VM_NAME>)
> $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference
```

You should get something like this:

```
Publisher    :
Offer        :
Sku          :
Version      :
ExactVersion : 1.0.0
Id           : <RESOURCE_ID_FOR_YOUR_IMAGE>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The accepted answer provides the OS image which could be different than the Azure Image. I think the original question was looking for this.

Comment: Perfect, this was hard to find! Is it also available in the portal?